# Browser-dependent CSS switch with JSF

Tags: css, jsf-2

I need some browser specific CSS in my JSF2 application (Mojarra 2.1, Tomcat 7).

I tried adding to my template:

```
    <!--[if IE 8]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="#{cfgs.externalCssUrlIE8}" />
    <![endif]-->
```

but the comments are not rendered since I also use:

```
<context-param>
    <!-- Removes any comments from the rendered HTML pages. -->
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

my problem... when I disable `javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS, I get a bunch of other problems.. Also I don't think my source-code comments belong to the generated pages.

I also tried to put the switch in CDATA like:

```
<![CDATA[
 <!--[if IE 7]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="#{cfgs.externalCssUrlIE7}" />
 <![endif]-->
]]>
```

but the inner < are rendered as html entities.. :-/, so its not working.

Question: Is there any other solution? Does any JSF2 tag exist to handle this? External tag libraries?

Thanks in advance,
Steve

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The only way is using `<h:outputText escape="false">`.

```xml
<h:outputText value="&lt;!--[if IE 8]&gt;&lt;link rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot; type=&quot;text/css&quot; href=&quot;#{cfgs.externalCssUrlIE8}&quot; /&gt;&lt;![endif]--&gt;" escape="false" />
```

Yes, this is a line of ugliness. But there's no other standard way.

---

**Update**: the JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) offers a [`<o:conditionalComment>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/conditionalComment) for exactly this purpose so that you don't need the ugly `<h:outputText escape="false">` anymore:

```
<o:conditionalComment if="IE 8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="#{cfgs.externalCssUrlIE8}" />
</o:conditionalComment>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works!
I also tried with <f:verbatim> but you are correct: The ugly escaped h:outputText seems to be the only solution.

Comment: You're welcome. Please note that `<f:verbatim>` is **deprecated** in JSF2. It has totally no value anymore as embedding plain HTML in Facelets is fully allowed/supported (which is also the case since JSF 1.2 on JSP). To render plain HTML conditionally in Facelets (as you'd previously do with `<f:verbatim rendered="#{some condition}">`, you should rather use `<ui:fragment>` instead.

Comment: nice workaround, even though its ugly... again you saved me :)

Comment: @BalusC `h:form` didn't render while using `h:outputText` inside `h:head`

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to work a solution using the inclusive syntax for conditional comments. Rather than writing `<!--[if IE 8]> ... <![endif]-->`, you would write `<![if !IE 8]> ... <![endif]>`.

In other words, without the dashes that make it a comment.

This is legitimate syntax. The intention of this syntax is that the conditional part is read by non-IE browsers, whereas with the syntax with the dashes, other browsers will ignore it.

Of course, this has obvious implications for your stylesheets -- the CSS included inside the conditional block will need to be for all browsers other than IE8 (you'll note the exclamation mark to I added above make it 'not IE8'); the IE8-specific stuff would need to be included in your standard stylesheet, to be overridden by the styles in the conditional block.

In other words, it's a reversal of functionality compared with what you're currently trying to do.

The important point for you is that doing it this way the conditional block is not a comment, and therefore shouldn't get removed by your parser.

You may need to rework a few things, but it should work.

The other option, of course, is to find an IE8-specific CSS hack. These do exist, but I would suggest avoiding them if possible, as you'll be making your CSS invalid, and there's always a danger of it breaking in some future browser version.

But if you want to go down this route, here's a link which gives you the answer: http://my.opera.com/dbloom/blog/2009/03/11/css-hack-for-ie8-standards-mode

But don't use that unless you *have* to.  :-)

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have a list of [if IE 7], [if IE 8] etc., so BalusC's answer makes a much simpler approach. Thanks for your explicit answer anyway.

Comment: @alfonx - no problem; as you say, @BalusC's answer is probably better for your situation, but hopefully you've found my answer useful nonetheless; even if it doesn't help this time.  :)

Answer (score 1):

BalusC's answer is the correct answer to my question. Still I want to share a JavaScript + CSS based solution I found: The [CSS Browser Selector](http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector).

Inserting [this minified line of JavaScript](https://raw.github.com/rafaelp/css_browser_selector/master/css_browser_selector.js) enables you to use OS- and browser-specific CSS selectors, e.g.:

> - html.gecko div#header { margin: 1em; }
> - .opera #header { margin: 1.2em; }
> - .ie .mylink { font-weight: bold; }
> - .mac.ie .mylink { font-weight: bold; }
> - .[os].[browser] .mylink { font-weight: bold; }

If your browser specific styling is still in the beginning, this might be a clearer solution compared to including many `.css` files.